# Sylow theorems in (Z/pZ)*

Tags: diffie-hellman

This might sound as a silly question but does the Sylow theorem III apply to (Z/pZ)*?

For Example for (Z/11Z)* we have the order of the group being 10 = 2 * 5.

I would expect to have only 1 Sylow 5-subgroup. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? The Sylow theorems apply to finite groups, and $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a finite group.

Comment: Well I have tried to come with a practical example for the third theorem of Sylow but it did not match my expectations :S

Comment: You can add the example to your question, so we could try to find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: Was going to write an answer, but @tylo summarizes it already. You indeed expect 1.

Comment: More concrete: the group $\langle 4\rangle=\{4,5,9,3,1\}$ is a subgroup of order 5 (and the only one).

Comment: While the Sylow theorems certainly apply to abeliqn groups, they are useless since in that case we have the more powerful structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia states the theorem as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Theorems):

> **Theorem 3**: Let $p$ be a prime factor with multiplicity $n$ of the
>   order of a finite group $G$, so that the order of $G$ can be written
>   as $p^nm$, where $n > 0$ and $p$ does not divide $m$. Let $n_p$ be the
>   number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Then the following hold:
>
> - $n_p$ divides $m$, which is the [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup) of the Sylow $p$-subgroup in $G$.
> - $n_p \equiv 1 \pmod p$.
> - $n_p = |G : N_G(P)|$, where $P$ is any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $N_G$ denotes the [normalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer).

Now note that $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*$ is a finite group with order $p-1$. As such the order has an ordinary prime factorization (ie you can pick $p,n,m$ as required) and all requirements for the theorem are fullfilled.

---

As for your example: There indeed appears to be only one Sylow 5-group in $(\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z)^*$.

- $n_5=1$ and $n_5=1$ divides $m=2$ (the index of this subgroup)
- $n_5=1\equiv 1\pmod 5$ which also holds
- $n_5=1=|G : N_G(P)|$ which is intuitively the index of the subset of elements of $G$ that commute with all the elements in all the Sylow $p$-subgroups in $G$. As we talk about a commutative group $G$ here, all elements in $G$ fullfill this condition.

The said subgroup is $\langle4\rangle=(\{1,3,4,5,9\},\cdot\bmod 11)$.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is silly, but as stated above I tried a numerical example but it did not much what I was expecting...

Comment: and can you show how this Sylow 5-group looks like? And do we have a generator for this Sylow 5-group? I t is probably where I am confused at.

Answer (score 2):

Although not really a question regarding cryptography, Sylow's theorems are quite boring for cyclic groups (or any commutative group):

- $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic and has order $p-1$
- Theorem 1 gives you the existance of subgroups with order of every prime power divisor of $p-1$, where every element has a power of that prime as its order.
- Theorem 2 on its own isn't all that useful, because conjugation of subgroups doesn't give you a different group in commutative groups: $g^{-1}Hg=g^{-1}gH=H$

Now the part you are asking about: The number of Sylow p-subgroups is fixed - it is $1$. Let's say we want a Sylow p-subgroup for prime $q$ (not to cause confusion with the group order $p-1$, and $q$ divides $p-1$). Theorem 2 states that Sylow groups are conjugate to each other, however conjugation always gives you the same subgroup. Assuming there are two Sylow p-subgroups, then theorem 2 would require them to be conjugate. However, that means those two subgroups are actually equivalent.

Comment: You probably mean $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ in your first bullet.

Comment: @tylo Thanks. Can you please show me an example of Sylow 5-group (see  my question above )

Comment: In $(\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})^*$ the elements of order $5$ are: $3,4,5,9$. Together with $1$ they are the subgroup of order $5$. And they are the quadratic residues, because taking the square of any element (which can have order $1,2,5,10$) results in order $5$ or $1$. And since the group is cyclic, this one is cyclic, too. And any element generates the entire subgroup.